# How to make an Outlook Rule based on the "Title" of the sender?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Can I make an Outlook Rule based on the "Title" of the sender that is saved on the active directory?

For example: a rule if the title of the sender is "Engineer" then the email should be forwarded to a certain address, another rule for "Consultant" which will forward it to another address, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research and tests, there seems to be no options that could create rules based on the "Title" of the sender. I also have tried to make an effort on message header, but the "Title" information may not be displayed in the header.

As an alternative, it's suggested to create some contact groups by the title and then create different rules for these contact groups to forward automatically.